# Change the width of the indicator in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, indicator

I'm facing a strange request by my client.

He want's the indicator inside the `UITextField` to be thiner. Can i change the indicator width? is this thing even possible?

Thanks,

Comment: It is possible, yes. AFAIK, it's not particularly easy. It requires overriding `drawRect`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to do width of indicator. You can do it by changing the bound text field. You can do it by drawing the rect by CGRectMake(0, 10, 0, 20)];

in given code i am showing indicator in search bar text box.

```
indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

indicator.frame = CGRectMake(Xaxis, searchBar.bounds.origin.y+6, 40.0, 40.0);
if(![pview.subviews containsObject:indicator])
        [pview addSubview:indicator];

[pview bringSubviewToFront:indicator];
```

it is looking like this. this may help u to understand. [image]

Comment: didn't quite understood what i need to do..can you add some code?

Comment: thanks for the replay but i am talking about the indicator for the text not a UIActivityIndicator

Comment: didn't understand can u plz explain.